# SetTimeout And SetImmediate with console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone please explain why i am getting this below two types of output for adding and removing console.log between setTimeout and setImmediate.

Why I am getting different output while executing example 1 and Why I am getting same output for example 2. Please tell me difference between setTimeout and setImmediate

**Example 1:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("inside timeout")
});

setImmediate(function(){
        console.log("inside immediate")
});
```

**Output:**

```
inside immediate
inside timeout
```

**Example 2:**

```
console.log(1)

setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("inside timeout")
});
console.log(2)
setImmediate(function(){
        console.log("inside immediate")
});
console.log(3)
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
inside timeout
inside immediate
```

Comment: `setImmediate` is non-standard. You should not be using it. Unless `node.js`

Comment: @weegee: It’s a standard part of Node.js. https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args

Comment: _This method is used to break up long-running operations and run a callback function immediately after the browser has completed other operations such as events and display updates._ From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) Thats why you will see it at the very end

Comment: [setImmediate() vs setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout) execution order between these two is never confirmed until they are called inside a common IO

Comment: Why I am getting different output each time while executing example 1 and please tell me difference between setTimeout and setImmediate

Comment: From the earlier link: “Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when callbacks will fire, nor of their ordering.” Unless you’re looking for something deeper, I’d say that’s the answer according to the documented API.

Comment: @Deepak - the docs are clear: `the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process:`

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks... One more doubt, then how my example 2 giving same output

Comment: I'm not sure @Deepak — there may be a good explanation from someone who knows the Node internals, but once the docs says it's not deterministic I consider it above my pay grade to think about the order and just accept that I shouldn't count on it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance

Answer (score 2):

Let's talk about the situation in `nodeJs`. Actually the order of the below code is can not be guarantee.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("inside timeout")
    });

    setImmediate(function(){
            console.log("inside immediate")
    });
```

If you run it many times, you will found that, in high probability it is

```
inside immediate
inside timeout,
```

but sometimes it's in reverse. You second demo is same.

In nodeJs there one thing call `event loop`, For the asynchronous function, the  `event loop` forward it to `libuv` and then it be forward to the OS. For eg. When the time in setTimeout is coming, the callback function be set into a queue, it will be invoked after the synchronous thread is done. For different asynchronous task there are four different queue, the `setTimeout's` queue is run before the `setImmediate's` queue.But the setTimeout's cut down return depend on the CPU's time slice, even the setTimeout(0), so it is not stable.

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**

Following your edit I'll add the answer given by **Mark Meyer** in the comments:

> the docs are clear: the order in which the two timers are executed is non-deterministic, as it is bound by the performance of the process

**Original answer**

setTimeout and setImmediate are asynchronous methods relying on the asynchronous stack.

Even if you are using setTimeout with no timer (which is the same as setImmediate), you would still put the callback on the asynchronous stack.

This stack is being executed as the main JS thread is freed.

So in your case this is what is happening:

- Execute console.log(1)
- Place the first callback on the stack
- Execute console.log(2)
- Place the second callback on the stack
- Execute console.log(3)
- Main thread is freed
- Execute first callback
- Execute console.log('inside timeout')
- Main thread is freed
- Execute second callback
- Execute console.log('inside immediate')

If you had a timer on the first timeout, it would take some time before actually going on the stack, and would end up behind the `inside immediate` output.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the order in the second example doesn't change if you swap the setImmediate and setTimeout.

Comment: You are right, but it was edited while I was answering. The original question was simply asking to explain the outputs